# Trouble loading CSV data in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm brand new to D3.js, so my apologies in advance if I'm overlooking something obvious, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what's not working here...

I've been inching my way through Scott Murray's *Interactive Data Visualization for the Web* and I've hit a block at Chapter 7. My goal is to load some simple data from a csv document, parse the first column as Date data, and then display. The head of the csv looks like this...

```
Date, Amount
9/15/17, 26
11/9/17, 31
11/30/17, 23
12/21/17, 26
2/7/18, 23
```

I run the code below (which comes directly from the book!) and...none of that seems to be happening. When I enter "dataset" into the console, it only seems to include the final row:

```
{Date: "01/31/17", Amount: "23"}
Amount: "23"
Date: "01/31/17"
```

I'm perplexed since, again, the code itself comes from the book. I've been working through previous chapters just fine until now. And yes, I'm running a local server. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks very much in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Time scale</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;
            var padding = 40;

            var dataset, xScale, yScale; 

            //For converting strings to Dates
            var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

            //Function for converting CSV values from strings to Dates and numbers
            var rowConverter = function(d) {
                return {
                    Date: parseTime(d.Date),
                    Amount: parseInt(d.Amount)
                };
            }

            //Load in the data
            d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter, function(data) {

                //Copy data into global dataset
                dataset = data;

                //Create scale functions
                xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                               .domain([
                                    d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.Date; }),
                                    d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.Date; })
                                ])
                               .range([padding, w - padding]);

                yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                               .domain([
                                    d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.Amount; }),
                                    d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.Amount; })
                                ])
                               .range([h - padding, padding]);

                //Create SVG element
                var svg = d3.select("body")
                            .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", w)
                            .attr("height", h);

                //Generate date labels first, so they are in back
                svg.selectAll("text")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("text")
                   .text(function(d) {
                        return formatTime(d.Date);
                   })
                   .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return xScale(d.Date) + 4;
                   })
                   .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return yScale(d.Amount) + 4;
                   })
                   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                   .attr("font-size", "11px")
                   .attr("fill", "#bbb");

                //Generate circles last, so they appear in front
                svg.selectAll("circle")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("circle")
                   .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return xScale(d.Date);
                   })
                   .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return yScale(d.Amount);
                   })
                   .attr("r", 2);

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The book‘s code is based on D3 **v4** whereas you seem to be using **v5**. The signature and the underlying workings of `d3.csv()` have changed significantly between these versions. The third parameter now is the row conversion function. Once you check the value of `dataset` it has finished processing the loaded file and set  the value to the last converted row. In your special case the solution is not to update your code but to downgrade the version in use.

Comment: I don‘t know the book but looking at the code you posted I am slightly concerned. A word of caution: setting an outer variable, namely `dataset`, from an asynchronous function is a very bad idea. It may work if you know what you are doing but generally it gives rise to scores of related problems because the code behaves differently from what you might expect. I consider this an anti-pattern. And, although this might be a single glitch when the author had a bad day, I‘d be on guard and question what was written. This is a bad thing while learning, though... Again, just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help here! I'm glad to hear it's a version issue. I was beginning to think I was losing my mind... Likewise, thanks for the word of caution about setting the outer variable. So far, the book is quite approachable for an absolute beginner, but I'll keep my eye out for this. I don't want to develop any bad habits.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
 d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter, function(data) {
--- your code --- 
});
```

Try this :

```
 d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter).then(data){
--- your code --- 
});
```